# MongoDB merge two aggregations from different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to backend and MongoDB so forgive me if my question sounds stupid.

I have two collections of **offers** and **products** detailed below

**Products**

```
[
  {
    "name": "product #1",
    "place": "place ID"
  },
  {
    "name": "product #2",
    "place": "place ID"
  },
  {
    "name": "product #3",
    "place": "place ID"
  }
]
```

**Offers**

```
[
  {
    "name": "offer #1",
    "place": "place ID"
  },
  {
    "name": "offer #2",
    "place": "place ID"
  },
  {
    "name": "offer #3",
    "place": "place ID"
  }
]
```

so my target is to merge the two aggregations of these two collections and get output similar to this one

```
[
  {
    "name": "offer #1",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "offer"
  },
  {
    "name": "product #1",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "product"
  },
  {
    "name": "offer #2",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "offer"
  },
  {
    "name": "offer #3",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "offer"
  },
  {
    "name": "product #2",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "product"
  },
  {
    "name": "product #3",
    "place": "place ID",
    "type": "product"
  }
]
```

should I aggregate on the product and offer collections or aggregate on place and group the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$facet` to add all products in a array and add type field
- `$lookup` with offers
- `$project` to add type field in offers `$map` through and concat both product and offer using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct final array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace final object in root

```
db.product.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      product: [
        { $addFields: { type: "product" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "offer",
      as: "offer",
      pipeline: []
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      final: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$product",
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$offer",
              in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { type: "offer" }] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$final" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$final" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l0KodTxy3a4)